# undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol Rails 4.1.x collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form element with:

`<%= f.collection_select :race, :id, Race.all, :id, :name, prompt: true %>`

This allows you to select your characters race in a text adventure I am creating. The goal is to have a drop down with all available races, select by name and have the params pass the id of that race back.

But when I load the page I get `undefined method 'merge' for :name:Symbol`.

I looked up the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) and I think I am doing it right, but I guess not? what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `f.` indicates you are in a `form_for` block? Which means the method signature of `f.collection_select` is different to just plain `collection_select`. The first parameter is automatically supplied by the `FormBuilder`, so if the `:race` is an attribute of the form object, which I assume is a Character, you just need:

```
<%= f.collection_select :race, Race.all, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
```

See the documentation for the [FormBuilder#collection_select method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_select).

Comment: Dude! you are so smart!