# rails collection_select should print my collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I got an error while trying to use collection_select ;)

I got this code in my view:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:channel, :channel_id, @channels, :id, :channelname, prompt: true) %>
```

in my controller I have this:

```
    @channels = Channel.all
```

and I got this error:

```
undefined method `merge' for :channelname:Symbol
```

Whats my failure ?

Thanks at all!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147069/collection-select-method-gives-error-in-rails-3-1-1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136478/undefined-method-merge-for-namesymbol-rails-4-1-x-collection-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs:

> collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method,
>   options = {}, html_options = {}) public

So therefore you should use:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:channel_id, Channel.all, :id, :channelname, prompt: true) %>
```

Comment: whats the difference between my one, my @channels should have the collection or not?

Comment: There is no difference. You can use @channels as per your example.

Comment: additional question, why is this not working: {prompt: t ("channel.add.prompt")}

Comment: prompt expects a string value or a boolean. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to load a string from my locales for translating

Comment: To use the translation helper method you need to have a translation defined in your locales folder and pass its key into the translation helper method, such as t(:your_defined_translation). [See here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-translations)

Comment: yes of course, I did ... have channel.add.prompt in my locales. Error is: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' ...:id, :channelname, {prompt: t "channel.add.prompt"}, class: ... ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use like

```
Channel.all.pluck(:id, :channelname)
```

For example take look at below

```
collection_select(
    :post, # field namespace 
    :author_id, # field name
    # result of these two params will be: <select name="post[author_id]">...

    # then you should specify some collection or array of rows.
    # It can be Author.where(..).order(..) or something like that. 
    # In your example it is:
    Author.all, 

    # then you should specify methods for generating options
    :id, # this is name of method that will be called for every row, result will be set as key
    :name_with_initial, # this is name of method that will be called for every row, result will be set as value

    # as a result, every option will be generated by the following rule: 
    # <option value=#{author.id}>#{author.name_with_initial}</option>
    # 'author' is an element in the collection or array

    :prompt => true # then you can specify some params. You can find them in the docs.
)
```

Comment: This doesn't make use of the form builder object which means any existing values wont automatically be preselected by rails when the view gets rendered.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= f.collection_select(:channel_id, :id, prompt: true) %>
```

Comment: There I got this error: wrong number of arguments (3 for 4..6)

Comment: how about this?
<%= f.collection_select(:channel_id, :id, @channels, prompt: true) %>

Comment: Neither of these provide the correct parameters for the collection_select method

Comment: Now I got this: undefined method `map' for :id:Symbol