# has_and_belongs_to_many Not Registering via collection_check_boxes in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to build a feature in my app that lets you create an `occasion` (i.e. Christmas 2018) and then select from many `people` which ones you need to buy gifts for that `occasion`.

Right now I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` like this:

```
  create_table "occasions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "person_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.date "date"
    t.text "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["person_id"], name: "index_occasions_on_person_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_occasions_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "occasions_people", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "occasion_id", null: false
    t.integer "person_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "relationship"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "middle_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.date "birthday"
    t.date "anniversary"
    t.date "other"
    t.string "other_date_name"
    t.text "notes"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "group"
    t.integer "occasions_id"
    t.index ["occasions_id"], name: "index_people_on_occasions_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_people_on_user_id"
  end
```

My relationship is put in both my `person.rb` model:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :occasions

  def full_name
    "#{last_name}, #{first_name}"
  end
end
```

And my `occasion.rb` model:

```
class Occasion < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have the correct (I think) params in my `people_controller`:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:relationship, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :birthday, :anniversary, :other, :other_date_name, :notes, :group, :user_id, :occasion_id)
end
```

And my `occasions_controller`:

```
def occasion_params
  params.require(:occasion).permit(:person_id, :user_id, :name, :date, :notes)
end
```

I have the following in my form to create a new `occasion` as a compromise between [this](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) documentation and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136478/undefined-method-merge-for-namesymbol-rails-4-1-x-collection-select) SO fix:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@occasion) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6 ">
        <%= f.input :name, required: true %>
      </div> <!-- col -->
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <%= f.label :date %>
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" data-datepicker-holder="#dateHolder"/>
        <%= f.hidden_field :date, id: "dateHolder", class: "hiddenDateField" %>
      </div> <!-- col -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :notes %>
      <%= f.text_area :notes, class: "form-control" %>
    </div> <!-- col -->
    <div class="form-group collection-checkboxes">
      <%= f.label "Who do you need to shop for?" %><br />
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:people, Person.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("last_name ASC"), :id, :full_name) %>
    </div> <!-- col -->
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions text-center">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-outline-primary", style: "margin-bottom: 10px" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I try to create a new `occasion`, the checkboxes appear as they should, but no matter what is checked, no association is registered and I get an `unpermitted parameter` for `:people`:

```
Started POST "/occasions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-06 14:59:05 -0700

Processing by OccasionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"utl5aK6RoJRxGKUsYbrz6tHs4uWzWMROXBMRJaxSqLd00CMHcBZ1L9WondisYvtWYJ2tw4X4QxMKAXSFurPV6g==", "occasion"=>{"name"=>"Test Occasion", "date"=>"2018-12-25", "notes"=>"This is a test.  It should have 3 people associated with this occasion.", "people"=>["", "22", "24", "25"]}, "commit"=>"Create Occasion"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98

Unpermitted parameter: :people
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
  Occasion Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "occasions" ("user_id", "name", "date", "notes", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["name", "Test Occasion"], ["date", "2018-12-25"], ["notes", "This is a test.  It should have 3 people associated with this occasion."], ["created_at", "2018-10-06 21:59:05.931738"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-06 21:59:05.931738"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
   (1.6ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/occasions

Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
```

Can anyone see what needs to be changed here to make it work as intended?  I'm new to HABTM associations.

**UPDATED SERVER LOG AFTER PAVAN'S ORIGINAL ANSWER**

```
Started POST "/occasions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-14 06:38:41 -0700
Processing by OccasionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XQ7RkDMBG/U+FECZcZ4A3eTmNgXVdAswbgIBdAErRNKTB4v/7YbOTpqkeG28RghhVZd5I+PUjG04EGTUF8o5jw==", "occasion"=>{"name"=>"Test", "date"=>"2018-10-01", "notes"=>"", "person_ids"=>["", "22", "24", "25"]}, "commit"=>"Create Occasion"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Person Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" IN (?, ?, ?)  [["id", 22], ["id", 24], ["id", 25]]
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:30
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
  Occasion Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "occasions" ("user_id", "name", "date", "notes", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["name", "Test"], ["date", "2018-10-01"], ["notes", ""], ["created_at", "2018-10-14 13:38:41.063659"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-14 13:38:41.063659"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
  Occasion::HABTM_People Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "occasions_people" ("occasion_id", "person_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["occasion_id", 2], ["person_id", 22]]
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
  Occasion::HABTM_People Create (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "occasions_people" ("occasion_id", "person_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["occasion_id", 2], ["person_id", 24]]
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
  Occasion::HABTM_People Create (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "occasions_people" ("occasion_id", "person_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["occasion_id", 2], ["person_id", 25]]
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
   (1.2ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/occasions_controller.rb:34
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/occasions
Completed 302 Found in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unpermitted parameter: :people

You need to change

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:people, Person.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("last_name ASC"), :id, :full_name) %>
```

to

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:person_ids, Person.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("last_name ASC"), :id, :full_name) %>
```

And whitelist `person_ids` in the `occassion_params`

```
def occasion_params
  params.require(:occasion).permit(:user_id, :name, :date, :notes, person_ids: [])
end
```

For more info, refer [`collection_check_boxes`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes)

**Update:**

In [*habtm*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association, the *joined table* stores the entries for `f_keys`. That said, you should remove `person_id` from `occasions` and `occasions_id` from `people` tables.

Comment: That gives me an `undefined method 'people_ids' for #<Occasion:0x00007faa6448d0d0>
Did you mean?  people` error

Comment: @Liz My bad. It should be `person_ids`

Comment: With everything changed to `person_ids` and nothing saying `people_ids` it doesn't error and includes the people in the params (`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"l26T9k1e/5dqNDV+29RpGLqQYJNnyMtOPw0lJ1B8vI9ZZ8mZk9kqLM6EDYoWDGGkC+EvtVFoTBNpH0CHRp3B0g==", "occasion"=>{"name"=>"Test", "date"=>"2018-10-01", "notes"=>"", "person_ids"=>["", "22", "24", "25"]}, "commit"=>"Create Occasion"}`), but it doesn't save them, as visible when I do Rails C `#<Occasion id: 1, person_id: nil...>`

Comment: @Liz Do you have the occasion_params as it is from my answer? Notice that I've removed `person_id` to make way for `person_ids: []`

Comment: Correct.  They're like this:  `params.require(:occasion).permit(:user_id, :name, :date, :notes, person_ids: [])`.  Still saving as `nil`.

Comment: @Liz Can you paste the server log in the question?

Comment: I added the newest server log to the OP.  Thank you for your help on this!

Comment: @Liz You should remove the respected `foreign_keys` from the `people` and `occasions` tables. The joint table `occasions_people` will store the entries for `foreign_keys`. That is how `has_and_belongs_to_many` works

Comment: I made a migration with this `remove_foreign_key :occasions, name: "index_occasions_on_person_id" remove_foreign_key :people, name: "index_people_on_occasions_id"` but it doesn't seem to have changed my `schema.rb` and it didn't change the outcome.  Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181839/discussion-between-pavan-and-liz).

Comment: And I did take your advice to implement a `has_many through: :associations` but have (as expected) broken everything.  Take a look if you want another (hopefully) easy-ish problem to fix:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805589/has-many-through-association-not-registering-in-rails-5-2